# How do I cast from IQueryable<T> to IQueryable<U> and <Func<T, bool>> to <Func<U, bool>> for fun?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics

Can someone please suggest how I might edit the following so that I can return `IQueryable<B>` from `repoA` given a predicate of `Func<B, bool>`?

Thanks in advance.

```
interface IRepo<T> {
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Func<T, bool> predicate);
} 

class A {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class RepoA : IRepo<A> {
    public IQueryable<A> FindBy(Func<A, bool> predicate) {
        return new EnumerableQuery<A>(new A[1]);
    }
}

class B {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class RepoB : IRepo<B> {
    IRepo<A> repoA = new RepoA();
    public IQueryable<B> FindBy(Func<B, bool> predicate) {
        var newPredicate = Magic goes here;
        var queryableA = repoA.FindBy(newPredicate);
        var queryableB = More magic goes here;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what you do for fun? go crazy with generics? :)

Comment: note that any text with `<`s and `>`s in *must* be formatted as code (backticks or four-space-indent) in order to appear. See my edit for an example.

Answer (score 5):

You would do this by *mapping* the `IQueryable<A>` to an `IQueryable<B>`.  The proper method for this is `Select`:

```
var queryableB = queryableA.Select(a => new B { Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name });
```

As for mapping the predicate - you could create a new predicate that does the mapping the same way:

```
var newPredicate = a => predicate(new B { Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name });
```

These work by creating a new B instance inline that is constructed using the properties of the passed in A instance...

Comment: @sarfeast - It would be nice if you would start accepting answers, or if the answer is not acceptable, add a comment explaining why.